# SQLite query not working in iphone

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have two tables as follows

```
CREATE TABLE messageTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, USERID INTEGER, FROMUSER TEXT, TOUSER TEXT, MESSAGEBODY TEXT, STATUS INTEGER, CREATEDTIME TEXT);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE chatPersonTable (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, USERID INTEGER, NAME TEXT, IMAGEURL TEXT, LASTACTIVE TEXT, LOGEDINUSERID INTEGER, STATUS INTEGER);
```

i want to fetch all columns from chatPersonTable for LOGEDINUSERID = "119"  along with the lastMessage (only last message) from messagetable for chatPersonTable.USERID = messageTable.USERID
i am using the following query but it is not working as expcted

```
 SELECT 
m.ID as CHATID, p.USERID, p.NAME, p.IMAGEURL, p.LASTACTIVE, p.logedinuserid, p.status, m.MESSAGEBODY, m.CREATEDTIME 
from chatPersonTable as p join messageTable as m

 on p.USERID = m.USERID 
 where p.LOGEDINUSERID = "119" 
 group by m.USERID order by m.CREATEDTIME desc
```

Comment: Not certain but `LOGEDINUSERID` (should be called `USERID`) is an `INTEGER` and `"119"` is a string.  Not sure what sqlite will think about that.

Comment: Not as a expected? You should either describe what you expect, or give us a error message.

Comment: my expected result is a table same as chatPeron + one more colum "messagebody" (from message table, which shold be the last message from that user)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use following query to get data.This will get data using self join

```
SELECT  m.ID as CHATID, p.USERID, p.NAME, p.IMAGEURL, p.LASTACTIVE, p.logedinuserid, p.status, m.MESSAGEBODY, m.CREATEDTIME ,**MAX(m.id)**
from chatPersonTable as p join messageTable as m on p.USERID = m.USERID where p.LOGEDINUSERID = "119" group by m.USERID
```

Thanks

Comment: Please highlight the difference between this query and the one presented in the question.

Comment: I have removed ordered by and use max(id) to get last unique row of messsage.